# Matplotlib mplot3d: fill edge to get 'convex surface'

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

This is how I plot my 3D surface plot.

The data is stored in (x,y,z) format:

```
tmp.dat
=======
1   1   1
2   1   4
3   1   1
1   2   4
2   2   5
3   2   4
1   3   1
2   3   4
3   3   1
```

To plot it I use following code:

```
def getMeshGrid(dat):
    x = dat[:,0]; y = dat[:,1]; z = dat[:,2]
    xVal, xIdx = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
    yVal, yIdx = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
    zVal = np.empty(xVal.shape+yVal.shape)
    zVal.fill(np.nan)
    zVal[xIdx, yIdx] = z
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.unique(x), np.unique(y))
    zz = zVal.T
    return (xx, yy, zz)

dat = np.loadtxt("tmp.dat")
X, Y, Z = getMeshGrid(dat)
fig = pl.figure()
axe = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
axe.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
pl.show()
```

The plot I get looks like this (which is ok): [image].
What I would like to do, however, is to also fill all the front face triangles in order to get a 'convex surface'.

If it is not clear, I would like to fill triangles in planes x=1, x=3, y=1, y=3, with edges [1,1], [3,1], [2,4] with maintaining the surface palette.

Thank you for any advice.